# Save a file in a startup-script on Google Cloud Platform when launching a compute engine

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, startupscript

I have a startup-script that works well when I launch a compute engine on google cloud. Nevertheless it doesn't seem to execute the following command.

`echo ${path} > ~/pd.txt`

Actually I can't retrieve my file when I look for it at the indicated path.
Do you have any clue on how I could save a file during startup-script ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When startup scripts run on GCE, they run under the `root` account.

The value of `~` depends on the user. Therefore for startup scripts `~` is `/root`. If you login with the user name `bob.jones` then `~` is `/home/bob.jones`.

You will find the results of `echo ${path} > ~/pd.txt` located at /root/pd.txt

A couple of tips with start scripts:

1. Do not expect $PATH to exist. Always specify the full path for both programs and filenames.
2. Do not use environment variables.
3. Do not use `~`. In your example specify the output filename full path.